# How to set model to null if ng-if parent is false in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I need ng-models to be null if the ng-if of parent is false

```
<label><input type="radio" ng-value="true" name="radio1" ng-model="response.answer1" /> Yes</label>
        <label class="margin-radio"><input type="radio" ng-value="false" name="radio1" ng-model="response.answer1" /> No</label>

<div ng-if="response.answer1">
        <input type="text" ng-model="response.answer2" />
</div>
```

When user select "Yes", the text input appears and then user can input something. If he does it and then click on "No", the text input will disappear but the value in response.answer2 remains, so I want it as null if the control is not there (ng-if="false").

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with ng-change directive

```
<input type="radio" ng-value="false" name="radio1" ng-model="response.answer1" ng-change="answerChanged()"/> No</label>
```

in controller:

```
$scope.answerChanged = function() {
    if($scope.response.answer1 ===  false) $scope.response.answer2 = null
};
```

Comment: I was thinking of it as my last option, because I have several cases like that, so I would need to create one ng-change (or a watch) for each of them and they are a lot, I was wondering if there is another solution

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use ng-init to assign null

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

});
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<label><input type="radio" ng-value="true" name="radio1" ng-model="response.answer1" /> Yes</label>
        <label class="margin-radio"><input type="radio" ng-value="false" name="radio1" ng-model="response.answer1" /> No</label>

<div ng-if="response.answer1">
        <input type="text" ng-model="response.answer2" ng-init="response.answer2=null"/>
</div>

</div>



</body>
</html>
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/ZVPJqJ

Comment: It works when the user select "Yes" again, but I want it as null when ng-if="false" as  I'm storing the information of response in database.